# To use lsf bsub command without all the verbosity output

Tags: submit, verbosity, lsf

My problem is that: I have a bash script that do something and then call 800 bsub jobs like this:

```
pids=
rm -f ~/.count-*
for i in `ls _some_files_`; do
    of=~/.count-${i}
    bsub -I "grep _something_ $i > $of" &
    pids="${!} ${pids}"
done
wait ${pids}
```

Then the scripts process the output files $of and echo the results.

The trouble is that I got a lot of lines like:

```
Job <7536> is submitted to default queue <interactive>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on hostA>>
```

It's actually 800 times the 3 lines above. Is there a way of suppressing this LSF lines?

I've tried in the loop above:

```
bsub -I "grep _something_ $i > $of" &> /dev/null
```

I does remove the LSF verbosity but instead of submitting almost all 800 jobs at once and then take less than 4 min to run, it submits just few jobs at a time and I have to wait more than an hour for the script to finish.

AFAIK lsf bsub doesn't seem to have a option to surpress all this verbosity. What can I do here?

Comment: Why use an interactive job? Also, I think there is an option to save the stdout to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress this output by setting the environment variable BSUB_QUIET to any value (including empty) before your bsub.  So, before your loop say you could add:

```
export BSUB_QUIET=
```

Then if you want to return it back to normal you can clear the variable with:

```
unset BSUB_QUIET
```

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Hi.. A related question. When launching the jobs in a script, how can I capture these messages? I am interested to trap the job ID. I want to keep track of it to kill it if necessary.
Thank you!

Comment: I believe they're written to stderr, not stdout.  Something like `bsub ... |& awk ...` should work

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using job dependencies and post-process the logfiles?

1) Run each "child" job (removing the "-Is") and output the IO to separate output file.  Each job should be submitted with a jobname (see -J).  the jobname could form an array.

2) Your final job would be dependent on the children finishing (see -w).

Besides running concurrent across the cluster, another advantage of this approach is that your overall process is not susceptible to IO issues.